# Blender hair in viewport looks nice and in render deformed

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I have styled the hair and everything and my viewport is set to display the same amount of hair as in the render, so I was expecting the same shape as in the render, but when I hit render the hair looks totally different and deformed.

Why is that happening? Roots are not even in the same direction.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Subdivision modifier on the hair emitter (head)? If the levels for viewport and render differ then the hair can look different

Answer (score 2):

You have to increase path steps in render dropdown menu under hair particle system, not just in viewport display

[image]

Comment: This caught me out for a while - good answer and a main reason why viewport and final renders of hair look different.